# Error while spying elements on Chrome browser in blue prism

Tags: blueprism

After spying element in web application in chrome browser and highlighting the element it throws an error like:

> Error - Highlighting results - No matching Web elements found

Using BP version 6

Comment: Right... that means that there were no elements found. We can't really help you without more information. You might be doing something wrong, as to what, I can't really say because I don't know what you have.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I get the same. Right after spying I press highlight and I get "No matching Web elements found"

Comment: **More Information Required**

Do you have the Blue Prism Browser Extension for Chrome installed and enabled?

When are you attempting to spy the relevant element?

 - After launching Chrome from the BP Object layer (via the Application Modeller, Tools bar, or Action stage)
 - Upon attaching to an already-running instance of Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are multimple chrome processes running in the background on your machine.

Solution:
 1. Open Task Manager and kill all instances of Chrome process.
 2. Launch new Chrome window from BluePrism
 3. You should be able to spy element of the displayed web page now.

Answer (score -1):

You should download the [Blue Prism Browser extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blue-prism-browser-extens/oaflhlmnamdgbgdgakpihkkdfapkebfp?hl=en-GB)

and try spying the elements again.